# react-i18next break line on Translation

Tags: html, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have a translation key, with a text where I need to have a new line `<br/>`.

As an example I have:

```
{
"key":"First line. <br/> Second line"
}
```

When calling `t("key")`, I still see the `<br/>` on my text and it is a single line.

I tried following [the examples on the documentation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#usage-with-simple-html-elements-like-less-than-br-greater-than-and-others-v10.4.0) with the `<Trans>` component, but I still don't get how to make the text translate and not stay as static text.

My code is the following:

```
 <Trans i18nKey="multiline">
   This text <br/> has multiple lines.
 </Trans>
```

I have two languages files:

English:   `"multiline":"This text <br/> has multiple lines."`

German:   `"multiline":"Dieser text <br/> hat meherere linien."`

What I expect is the text changing, showing the language selected. The problem is I get the text only in english.

Comment: Share your code of how you tried to use the `<Trans>` component, so we can see what the issues are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this function and defined my translations with a `\n` for line breaks

```js
function MultilineTranslation({text}) {
  const items = text.split('\n')
  return (
    <>
    { items.map(item => <p>{item}</p>)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Trans` component offers different advanced use cases. Luckily, keeping basic HTML nodes is default behavior!

You can go ahead and use it like follows:

```
<Trans i18nKey="key">
  First line. <br/> Second line
</Trans>
```

You can find the official documentation [here](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#usage-with-simple-html-elements-like-less-than-br-greater-than-and-others-v10.4.0).